# Flags not getting actioned

Tags: support, flags

Are we falling short of staff or is there some other reason why the flags are not getting actioned?

There are some important flags that I have raised which have not been actioned.

If you look at the screenshot, there are two flags which were raised on **16th August** but are still pending. They are not *that important* but the most recent ones (**August 25**) definitely are. This particular user has two accounts and it has not been actioned yet.

The ones raised on **August 17** were taken care of by the community members.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the moderators simply don't know what to do with the flag.

Comment: i doubt that is the case @ShadowWizard.

Comment: Why? Regarding the last flag, maybe the moderators are not sure if the answer really fits as a comment. Regarding the one before it, dead link does not always mean the answer should be deleted. And if it just should be edited out, that's not the job of the moderators.

Comment: Ah.. You are referring to those. I was thinking that you were referring to duplicate account flags :)

Comment: Well, moderators can't merge accounts any more, only community managers. So naturally, it takes longer. Plus, this should come from the user, unless of course used for bad actions, in which case you should elaborate in the flag. (Then one account is deleted while the other is warned or suspended.)

Comment: Both the accounts as of now are live. Pardon my ignorance but your name sounds familiar... were you a moderator?

Comment: Like I said, as long as the accounts do not vote for each other or voting on same posts it's fine for one person to have more than one account. Many long time users (including myself) have such accounts, usually used to test things, sometimes just out of spite. As for moderator, not here or on Stack Overflow, but in a forum long years ago. (aspfree, maybe you were there too?)

Comment: No I was not in aspfree. :)

Comment: Well, so you just see me around here a lot, as I'm pretty active. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be flagging a post because it has a dead link.  If the post answers the question without the link then either update the link, or remove it from the post, and if the link is essential then the post isn't an answer, and flag using *that* reason.

Comment: @Servy. I think you are missing the point here. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @SiddharthRout If I was trying to answer your question I'd have posted an answer.  The point remains that 3 of your 4 flags (at least, without seeing the post for the 4th flag) *shouldn't have been cast in the first place*.  One of the best ways of dealing with the problems mods have handling flags is to *not submit flags for things that don't merit moderator attention*; not only does this prevent you waiting a while to get your flag handled, but it means that many less flags for the mods, helping them keep up with the queue more effectively.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are currently 1020 flags in the Stack Overflow moderator queue, 365 of them custom flags.

Custom flags can take wildly variable amounts of time to be handled, depending on when they come in, what they're surrounded by, what they're about, and who's around. Our biggest problem with custom flags is that they are completely unsorted, so flags about someone being abusive can sit right next to someone abusing flags to demand that moderators answer their question. Good flags can slip to the back of the pile if they're surrounded by bad ones.

There's a userscript that a few of us can fall back on to help pull out common flag types based on keywords, but it's not perfect. Better sorting of these in the moderator tools is something that SE has been working on, but it's not here yet.

Also, it's the summer in the northern hemisphere and many moderators take vacations or otherwise spend less time around the site. No "staff" tend to be involved in this, just the volunteer moderators, and we have lives outside of the site that sometimes prevent us from being as active. Things will return to normal once the season has passed.

I should point out that these flags won't expire, and the issues they point to aren't necessarily immediate problems. It isn't inherently troubling if someone has multiple accounts, for example, only if those accounts are used in a way that lets you do things you wouldn't be able to with a single account. We'll get to the flags eventually, and we've been working through the longer-standing custom flags.

Comment: Would it be helpful for the moderators if us mortals know (and use) the keywords that are used to filter on so that the custom flags raised by those who care get in the *right* filter?

Comment: @rene - That depends entirely on who's using the userscript. The only preset categories in the userscript right now based on keywords are "Migration requests", "Owner requests post deletion", "Duplicates", "Plagiarism", "Merge requests", "Link-only answer", "Dead links", and "Reopen requests". I use a few keywords to find "plz answer this" flags to decline *en masse*, but others vary based on what I'm trying to filter for. Usually, I use this script only when processing a lot of flags at once, so this will only be really effective when it's in the main interface.

Comment: @rene that sounds like information that would be open to abuse

Comment: Brad, as I suspected your answer sure makes sense. As I suspected, we are falling short of staff because of the reasons given in your post. Well in that case, let's wait patiently :)

Comment: @Cai I don't think it is wise to abuse stuff that puts your abuse in front of a moderator ....

Comment: @rene I completely agree... That doesn't mean people wouldn't do it

Comment: They can do it once ... having seen Brad in action ...

Comment: Could that script be extended with a regex for "robo reviewer", "robo-approves", etc? I think flags on robo-reviewers are best handled when the collected evidence is still fresh.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - It could be extended with a lot of things. It was put together quickly as an experiment, only a few moderators use it, and even then it's only used from time to time. Until these flags are sorted in the main interface, relying on certain keywords to up the priority of a flag won't be a good bet.

Answer (score 3):

Custom Moderator flags go into the moderator review queue, and they don't age away. There are a whole lot of moderator flags in there, so your might take time to get handled. August 16th is only 13 days away, thats less then 2 weeks.

> Are we falling short of staff or is there some other reason why the
>   flags are not getting actioned?

Give it some time, Moderator flags may take a month or more if there is backlog in the queue, especially on Stack Overflow where the moderators get thousands of flags daily.

Comment: `Give it some time, Moderator flags may take a month or more if there is backlog in the queue` I am wondering the havoc duplicate accounts can create in that time period. Any way these can be pushed right on top of the queue? I think and I could be wrong, the "Spam" flag gets the highest priority at the moment?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, there is no way to get pushed to the top of the queue. But having 2 accounts isn't hard to remedy - They can be merged and/or destroyed long after the fact. If the guy plans on doing fraud voting, he's not getting away with it, whether your flag takes 2 days or a month to handle.

Comment: If this is what the general consensus is then I will accept this as an answer. Else I would definitely like to hear what a moderator has to say. let's give this post some time :)

Comment: Spam flags get handled automatically once enough of them are cast on a single post.

Comment: @Bart I am pretty sure spam flags reach a different moderator queue, so have higher priority. In low traffic sites where not enough users are around to cast the flags, it's important. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Probably @ShadowWizard, just saying that spam flags may seem to be handled more rapidly because they get auto-nuked.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think when flagging dupe accounts one better be prepared that some of these flags may hang for long. Many of these are straightforward but there is a chance for flag to reveal signs of sophisticated sock / voting ring, in that case mods / SE dev team may choose to take time to deeper investigate. IIRC 3 or 4 of my own flags on complicated cases took month or more to handle